# Create xml schema and verify in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

I am new in the working with the XML and XML schema.

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MainDoc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/DocHeader">
  <DocHeader>
    <TypeVersion>5.0</TypeVersion>
    <Dest>
      <Id Auther="zzz">2</Id>
    </Dest>
  </DocHeader>
 </MainDoc>
```

I already referred to https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_text.asp

but it seems not working for my case (I have multiple elements with the attributes), so any one can tell me what will be the exact schema for the above XML?

XML Schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="MainDoc">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="DocHeader">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="TypeVersion" type="xs:double"/>               
            <xs:element name="Dest" type="xs:string">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Id">
                            <xs:complexType>
                             <xs:simpleContent>
                                  <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                                   <xs:attribute name="Author" type="xs:string"/>
                                  </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Code I am trying to read in C#:

```
XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
schema.Add("", "PATH_OF_XSD_FILE");
```

Getting error in C#:

> The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType.

Comment: Exact schema? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I have created the xsd file for the above xml. but i am getting error."The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType."

Comment: So you are trying to create this xsd file in c#?

Comment: Actually i want to verify the xml file using the xsd file. Check the xsd file code i attached for the sample xml

Comment: You specified the elements `Sender` and `Receiver` to be both of type `xs:string` as well as of a complexType. Obviously, these cannot both be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per klaus Gutter, if complex type is used, type will come as we can use `base` for that.
check following code:

```
<xs:element name="Dest">                
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Id">                      
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:attribute name="Auther" type="xs:string" />
                                  </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
```